# Android Service with multiple Threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've set up a ListView. Each of the ListView-Items contains a ToggleButton, 
which starts or stops a Thread in a Service.

The threads need to run as long as the toggleButtons are activated. If the activity stops, the service and the activated threads need to continue.

```
//In MainActivity
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("id",listviewPosition);
startService(intent);
}


//MyService
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Thread(startId) starten
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread(String.valueOf(startId));
    thread.start();
    // Threads looper holen und beim servicehandler benutzen
    serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(thread.getLooper());
    listServericeHandler.add(serviceHandler);
    //message ausm pool holen
    Message msg = serviceHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.arg1 = startId;
    serviceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    return START_STICKY;
}

private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
    super(looper);
    }

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
while (continueUntilToggleButtonIsDeactivated) {
Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Thread " + tring.valueOf(msg.arg1)
                + " running: " + url.toExternalForm());
synchronized (this) {
        try {
            //do stuff
            wait(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        }
    }
}
}
```

So, I'm trying to start a thread in the `OnStartCommand()` every time I activate a toggleButton.

What I don't know is how to stop the threads and get the out of the while-loop.

Comment: In the while loop declaration is `continueUntilToggleButtonIsDeactivated` a variable, or just your explanation?  If it is a variable then where are you setting it?

Comment: that should be some sort of explanation. im tryed setting a variable when onCheckedChanged gets called but i cant handle multiple threads that way.

Comment: ^ Need this information to help. How are you handling the `continueUntilToggleButtonIsDeactivated` flag. Set it to false, when you stop the thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a flag for the while loop to abide by to know when to stop.  For example:

```
private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    private volatile boolean _continueRunning = true;

    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    public void stopRunning() {
        _continueRunning = false;
        this.notify(); //Interrupts the wait
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        while (_continueRunning) { //Watches the variable
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Thread " + tring.valueOf(msg.arg1)
                                + " running: " + url.toExternalForm());

        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                //do stuff
                wait(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You should create your handler in the `onCreate()` method of the service.  The `onStartCommand` method informs you of new messages.

```
//In your Service Class
...
private ServiceHandler _serviceHandler;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceClassName");
    thread.start();

    // Threads looper holen und beim servicehandler benutzen
    serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(thread.getLooper());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //message ausm pool holen
    Message msg = _serviceHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.arg1 = startId;
    serviceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    return START_STICKY;
}

private class mRunnable implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean _continueRunning = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (_continueRunning) { //Watches the variable
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    //do stuff
                    wait(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //Purposefully left blank
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopRunning() {
        _continueRunning = false;
        this.notify();
    }
}
```

Then you change your ServiceHandler to

```
private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    //TODO whatever type of list you need
    private List<mRunnable> _runningThreads = new LinkedList<mRunnable>();

    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        mRunnable runnable = new mRunnable();
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well i see how you handled that, but i still dont know how i get multiple threads working that way. The service stops if i stop one thread and if a second thread is running i get a nullpointerexception after calling stopRunning(). Is calling the onStartCommand() the right way to starta new thread ?

Comment: Haha.  You're welcome.  I also updated with a different way to do it as well (since I apparently didn't notice your commend beforehand).