# Pass large string-arrays to another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, arrays

I am trying to pass a large string-array of maybe 2 or 3 MB to another activity. The chunk is not passed and the only thing I can see in the logcat about what happend is ...

!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

I tried to create my own class which implements Serializable, put a mutator there in which I put my String, then pass the Object reference to intent.putExtra(key, Serializable obj)

the code:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalculationsActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("mc", mc);
```

Is there an easy solution to this issue - that is to pass a large string-array to another activity?

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {
   private String[] str;

   public void setString(String[] str) {
       this.str = str;  
   }

   public String[] getString() {
       return this.str;
   }
}
```

I thought that passing just a reference wouldnt cause this. Reference is not more than a memoryaddress

Comment: there is a limit to the size of what you can pass in the bundle of an intent. Passing that limit results in the error you describe. I have observed on some device that it is ~500K, although I don't know if that is a systematic value. Solutions include using static variables, file or database writing, rethinking if you really need to pass 2M of data.

Comment: It seems rather weird that you try to pass a 3MB `String[]` to another `Activity`. I think we might be able to find a much simpler solution if you explain what you are trying to do in the first place.

Comment: @njzk2 - hello, the reason I do this is because I want the heavy textfiles to be downloaded at the app-startup. AFter 3-4 seconds the user comes to the firstactivity - a GUI where she/he can choose between different alternatives. From this on all heavy loading is done - I want to avoid loading later on in the app. Thanks

Comment: I would save the files on the file system, and simply pass the path in the intent.

Comment: @XaverKapeller - read above - isn't it good to have all loading done when the app starts up?

Comment: also, all this looks like a job for a Service, rather than several activities

Comment: @njzk2 - I want it to be stored in RAM becuase of speed

Comment: @user3155478 No, that is bad. Users shouldn't have to wait for your app to load. Especially not when first opening it. This is a clear cut case for a `Service`.

Comment: @user3155478 Oh, and use a database.

Comment: don't worry about speed. you are downloading these files. This is going to be slow. reading and writing to local storage is going to be negligible in regard.

Comment: @XaverKapeller - database? - on the Pacific Ocean with a Sail Boat. This is an app about Celestial navigation.

Comment: @user3155478 I have no idea what you mean? So? What has that to do with wheter to use a database?

Comment: Thanks for all input - I'll really consider this. But I was thinking - at startuptime, at the most 4 seconds, I can show I nice splashscreen, put the downloading in a background thread. Well I'll see :-)

Comment: @user3155478 Splashscreens are bad. Don't use one. It's a sign of a badly designed app and is against Google's app design guidelines. If your app needs to load data at startup than you are doing something wrong. And if you don't need to load data at startup than there is no reason to have a Splashscreen and make the user wait. Things like this can make or break user engagement of your app. Nobody is going to keep using your app if he has to wait 5 seconds each time it starts. It would just annoy the users.

Comment: @XaverKapeller thanks for input - worth a lot. I am relative new to app-programming. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, using Local files (in your sandboxed directory) or database entries will probably be the way to go.  However, if you want to do remote (e.g. ftp) hosting of the file and still load them when the application loads you should use a Service. (see the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)).

I have two previous answers explaining services in more depth that you should look at.

[How to use threads and services. Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356772/how-to-use-threads-and-services-android/20357130#20357130)
and
[Android Service with multiple Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405677/android-service-with-multiple-threads/20406022#20406022)

Essentially though there are two types, a bound thread (which lives with either an activity or the application) and intent services (which can always be active, or only active when the app is open).  What you would want is probably the former which would look something like what is in the first link.

here is a snippet

```
public class BoundService extends Service {
    private final BackgroundBinder _binder = new BackgroundBinder();

    //Binding to the Application context means that it will be destroyed (unbound) with the app
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return _binder;
    }

    //TODO: create your methods that you need here (or link actTwo)
    // Making sure to call it on a separate thread with AsyncTask or Thread

    public class BackgroundBinder extends Binder {
        public BoundService getService() {
            return BoundService.this;
        }
    }
}
```